# Config.groovy in grails

Tags: grails, groovy

In Config.groovy file we are assigning the value of appName to grails.project.groupId

grails.project.groupId = appName

My question is from where we are getting the value for appName.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To get the appName in a config file that you're including with grails.config.locations you can use-

```
appName = grails.util.Metadata.current.'app.name'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use: grailsApplication.config.my.property

You would have access to all properties defined in config File.